# How to scale a long LibreOffice Calc sheet to fit on two pages when exporting to PDF?

Tags: pdf, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

I have Libreoffice and I want to export a long calc sheet to a pdf document with the  fit-to-page function from the page preview in the file menu but it doesn't seems to work. I want to fit my sheet up to 2 pages because it's unreadable otherwise. When I export the sheet it gives only one page and the sheet is unreadable.

Comment: (knowing it isn't what you asked) in Excel, I would configure the page settings and probably preview the pages before exporting. Maybe something similar exists.

Comment: In openoffice there is a function fit-to-page in the page preview. But it doesn't work?

Comment: It's working, at least for me. Try to upload example `.ods`. What version of LibreOffice? You may look at [bugzilla](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/BugReport).

Comment: Could you please describe step-by-step what did you try. There are different fit-to-x options that may affect only the page display, not the print layout, and different LibreOffice version which offer different features.

Comment: Was my answer helpful for you?

Comment: @tohuwawohu:No,what is the sheet tab? AFAIK my question is very accurate. BTW. I use Linux version.

Comment: Linux of Windows doesn't differ in this point. Regarding the Sheet tab, i've highlighted the dropdown where you can select the scaling mode. In your case, select the third option (**Fit print range(s) on number of pages**) and set the page number to `2`. This should give a PDF output scaled to two pages. I've emended my answer.

Comment: If there's still an issue with the answer (point missing, not clearly explained), please feel free to add a comment.

Comment: Thank you. It works but only after a reboot.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940236/how-to-generate-pdf-from-a-libreoffice-calc-sheet-fitting-the-page-width

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use the page preview options to scale the PDF output. Output scaling has to be done using the Sheet properties in the Page Style dialogue (Select the Menu **`Format`** -> **`Page...`** -> **`Sheet Tab`**).

There, you have different options to make the Calc output fit to a certain number of pages. In the following screenshot, the **`Scale`** options are highlighted, especially the **`Scaling mode`** ComboBox:

[image]

To scale the PDF output to two pages, just select the third option (**Fit print range(s) on number of pages**) from the `Scaling Mode` ComboBox and set the page number to `2`. This should give a PDF output scaled to two pages:

[image]